# How to customize back navigation on Apple tvOS?

Tags: tvos

I am developing an application for tvOS. In my app users select their country, states and districts respectively in different view controllers. After selections, App displays a page with the information related to users' selections. When user presses the menu button in this page, I want the app to exit, but the app goes to previous page which is district selection view controller.

How can I make the app exit in this situation. I don't want user to go back all the pages to exit the app.

Comment: when you say _"I want the app to exit"_, do you mean _terminate_ the app, go back to the _very first_ view of your app?

Comment: I want app to terminate or go to the main screen (app can still be in background)

Comment: Similar: [How can I put an Apple TV app in background after pressing the Menu button](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34335505/2108547).

Comment: Look at this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/42468705/276965

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335505/how-can-i-put-an-apple-tv-app-in-background-after-pressing-the-menu-button) question that [Daniel Storm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2108547/daniel-storm) mentioned. Here is the swift code:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
    tapRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.Menu.rawValue)]
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
}

func handleTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        app.performSelector(Selector("suspend"))
    }
}
```

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Keep in mind this is private API (even though using the selector trick) that comes with a risk. If you want your app to suspend by the press of menu button, what should work is to *not* capture the menu button, ie. no gesture recognizer for the menu button, and no raw game controller processing. The default action is then that the system suspends your app.