# Allow Menu button to exit tvOS app when pressed on presented modal view controller

Tags: storyboard, tvos, siri-remote

I have a tvOS app, with a `UITabBarController` as the main entry point for the main storyboard. If the user is not logged in, the `UITabBarController` presents a `LoginViewController` modally.

When the user presses the Menu button on the Siri remote, the system automatically dismiss the `LoginViewController` and shows the `UITabBarController`. I want the app to instead exit to the tvOS headboard.

Expect the solution to involve either a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to override the Menu button action, or overriding `pressesBegan/pressesTouched`, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34335505/2108547) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34358073/2108547).

Comment: Those answers use a private API

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68052750/294884

Answer (score 5):

This following snippet works, and is acceptable behavior based on the expected behavior for a menu button in Apples [HIG for Remotes and Interactions](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/remote-and-interaction/)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapped")
    tapRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.Menu.rawValue)];
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
}

func tapped() {
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
}
```

2020s syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68052750/294884

Comment: Although this 'works', it is discouraged by Apple to exit programatically https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/StartingStopping.html

Comment: @RicSantos keep in mind the link you provided is about iOS, not tvOS. If you take a look at the [Remote and Interactions HIG](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/remote-and-interaction/), for tvOS, you will notice that the expected behavior in an app for the menu button is "Returns to previous screen." AND "Exits to Apple TV Home screen."

Comment: Here's the correct Remote HIG page: https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/remote-and-controllers/

Comment: `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` works with Xcode9.1, tvOS 11.1 on Apple TV 4K simulator.

Comment: Setting aside Apple's opinion on it.  Currently (2023) it essentially **"does not work"**.  It works very badly on simulators, and on real TVs with a real stack of apps running, it often fails or behaves totally unacceptably. (See recent answer.)  It's a tricky problem

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar situation, it looked like this:

```
               +--------------------+
        ------>| MainViewController |
               +--------------------+
                         |
           +-------------+-------------+
           |                           |
           v                           v
+---------------------+      +--------------------+
| LoginViewController |      | HomeViewController |
+---------------------+      +--------------------+
```

If either `LoginViewController` or `HomeViewController` are presented then I want the menu button to dismiss the app and return to the TV home screen, *not* to `MainViewController`.

After much Googling, I settled upon this solution and it seems to work well without triggering warnings or requiring a call to `exit`.

```swift
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = segue.destination
    }
}
```

Hope this is helpful to somebody out there

Answer (score 0):

### For 2023 ...

Regarding this very old question. I'd like to point out that

```
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
```

solutions *don't really work* now.

The problem is, as you'll see, they introduce a 3-4 second delay when you quit. In simulator, it will work fine (with the 3-4 second delay) but on a device, additionally it will plain fail with erratic results.

I honestly feel the only way is to set up TV apps "naturally" - basically so that the "main screen" is indeed fundamentally you're "first / wrapper" screen, and then a back click by the user will indeed work completely naturally.

As of 2023, unless I've missed something - and that may be the case - I honestly believe that "natural" approach is the only way to handle TV apps, so that people can exit.

Unfortunately that seems to be the state of play.